# Alternative for multiple pthreads joining one pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I read in `man pthread_join` that multiple pthreads cannot join a pthread that has already been joined. Is there another way to achieve the same result? Multiple pthreads suspend themselves until some specific pthread tells them "you may continue"? And how would that work? (in C language)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of `pthread_join` is different from what you have asked "*Multiple pthreads suspend themselves until some specific pthread tells them "you may continue"?*"

Incase of pthread_join, a thread waits for other threads to complete before proceeding further.

If you want multiple threads to wait for a signal from other thread (or threads), you can try exploring [pthread_cond_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) and [pthread_cond_signal](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) API(s)

Comment: I wish there was an example for that, because it seems extremely confusing. I will check it out though, thank you.